# Is it possible to shade a dependency?

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

My project has dependencies `lib-A` and **third-party** `lib-B:1.0` in my pom. But `lib-A` depends on `lib-b:2.0`. From my understanding, if `lib-A` had a shaded version of `lib-b` then that would solve the problem, correct? ***But the issue is `lib-b` is a third-party dependency which I have no control over.***

Is there a work around so my project and `lib-A` will work correctly with different version of `lib-b`?

Answer (score 4):

Workaround is to shade `lib-b` with your project.

**Edit :**

Create new project say `shaded-lib-b` with `lib-b` as dependency and in your project you need have dependency for `shaded-lib-b` and now package name of `lib-b` will be `my.shaded.example`

pom.xml for shaded-lib-b

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

       <groupId>my.shaded.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>shaded-lib-b</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>lib-b</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.4.1</version>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <phase>package</phase>
           <goals>
             <goal>shade</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
             <relocations>
               <relocation>
                 <pattern>com.example</pattern>
                 <shadedPattern>my.shaded.example</shadedPattern>
               </relocation>
             </relocations>
             <transformers>
               <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer" />
             </transformers>
           </configuration>
         </execution>
       </executions>
     </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: How do I shade `lib-b`if it's a third-party lib?

Comment: can I shade the same library with different versions? Or only once per library?